Show FoodCategoryList in view in ASP.NET Core
I have this view model that list some food in database:
public async Task<IActionResult> FilterFoodList(FilterFoodViewModel filterFoodViewModel )
{
    var result = await _foodService.FilterFoodList(filterFoodViewModel);
 
    return View(result);
}

Food have relation with FoodCategory and FoodSelectedCategory
and have access to them.
How can I show FoodCategory for each food in view?
I try it but can not:
<td>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(food.FoodTitle))
{
    var category = Model.FoodCategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FoodCategoryId == food.FoodId);
   
    if (category != null)
    {
        <span>@category.FoodCategoryTitle</span>
    }
}
</td>


Please show your Model structure to understand better how you are relating the FoodCategory and FoodSelectedCategory. You have yourself answered your own question on this line: How can I show FoodCategory for each food in view , by using a for-each loop. You need to do a GroupBy on the FoodCategory : Model.FoodCategories.GroupBy(c=>c.FoodCategoryTitle).Select(c=>c)

This is related how _foodService.FilterFoodList works, we need to know the filterFoodViewModel make up and will it also query the the related FoodCategoryTitle.

you can do a foreach in Razor
